# Javascript If-else statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

new to javascript but trying a basic 'if, else' statement and can't get it to work...

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 1")')) {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness1.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 1');
    }
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 2")')) {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness2.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 2');
    }
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 3")')) {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness3.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 3');
    }
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 4")')) {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness4.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 4');
    }
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 5")')) {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness5.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 5');
    }
    else {
    $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness1to5.png)'}).text('Choose your perfect firmness');
 }
 });
```

I know there must be a bette way to do this, please help :)

Thanks

P

Comment: `jQuery()` returns an object, even if it doesnt find anything, so just checking against `jQuery(...)` will always be truthy, check its length ie: `jQuery(...).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 1")').length) {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness1.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 1');
    }
    else if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 2")').length) {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness2.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 2');
    }
    else if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 3")').length) {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness3.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 3');
    }
    else if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 4")').length) {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness4.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 4');
    }
    else if ($('.feature:contains("Firmness Rating 5")').length) {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness5.png)'}).text('Firmness Rating 5');
    }
    else {
        $('#firm').css({'background-image': 'url(firmness1to5.png)'}).text('Choose your perfect firmness');
    }
 });
```

If you want many if statements chained, use `else if`.

Also, to check if a jQuery selector was able to select any elements, use `$(selector).length`, which returns the number of matched elements. `if(number)` returns `true` with a positive value and `false` with 0 or negative. So, if your selector matches any elements, `if($(selector).length)` returns `true`.

Comment: Everydays a school day :) Awesome - works great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ìf` as you were using it:

```
if(some condition){
  run code
}
if(some condition){
  run code
}
```

Instead do this:

```
if(some condition){
  run code
}
else if( some condition){
  run code
}
```